# Django Template Images

Tags: django, image, templates

Take a simple view like this:

```
def my_gallery(request):
    images= ?
    t = Template("<html><body>Here my images from XY {{ images }}.</body></html>")
    html = t.render(Context({'images': ? }))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

How do I have to define the variable images/ What do I have to fill in the Context 
so that Django displays me:

1 image
more than 1 image
1 soundfile
more than 1 soundfiles

on the site my_gallery

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Do you want the view to render the string "1 image more than 1 image ... "?

Comment: I was trying to display one or multiple images (= jpeg, gif, etc) and or soundfiles on one url

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want to know..

```
#/appname/model.py
from django.db import models

class MyImages(models.Model):
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='/upload_path/')


#/appname/views.py
from appname.models import MyImages
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_gallery(request, template='gallery.html'):

    obj_images= MyImages.objects.all()

    kwvars = {
        'images': obj_images,
    }

    return render_to_response(template, kwvars, RequestContext(request))


 #gallery.html
 ...
 {% for image in images %}
     {{ images.url }}
 {% endfor %}
```